# Mosca with https

Tags: javascript, node.js, mqtt

I need to attach Mosca server to a https server. As I can see in Mosca docs they have an attachHttpServer method with similar purpose as I need but I can't find anything with https. Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried just passing a https object to the that method?

Comment: yes, it was what I did firstly

Comment: Edit the question to include what happened when you did